# Почему не выводится migx поле через getImageList MODX Revo?

Tags: modx, revo, migx

Сделал поле migx

```
[{
"caption":"Новый материал к уроку",
"fields": [
{
"field":"title",
"caption":"Название материала",
"inputTVtype":"text"
},
{
"field":"pdf",
"caption":"Ссылка на файл материала",
"inputTVtype":"file"
}]
}]
```

Вызываю его в шаблоне для ресурсов.
Если вызывать обычным образов типа `[[*material]]`, то возвращается, как мне написали, json параметры строки (или что-то вроде того).

**`[{"MIGX_id":"1","title":"Материал 1","pdf":"materiali-dlya-urokov/test.docx"}]`**

Но если вызывать через *getImageList*

```
[[getImageList?
    &docid=`[[*id]]`
    &tvname=`material`
    &tpl=`stuff`
    ]]
```

то вообще ничего не выводится.

Чанк:

```
<li>[[+material]]</li>
```

Пытаюсь чтобы в итоге вывелось имя файла и было оно ссылкой, в настройке этого доп поля тип вывода указал **URL**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чанк: `<li>[[+pdf]]</li>`
При вызове `getImageList` `&tvname` - это имя tv поля (`material`), а в чанке уже используются поля которые описаны в этом дополнительном поле, раздел field (`[[+title]]` и `[[+pdf]]`)

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но по-прежнему не выводится ничего, даже так как Вы написали.

Comment: Странно, попробуйте без чанка: &tpl=` `@CODE: <li>[[+pdf]]</li>` ` уберите &docid по умолчанию он [[*id]]

Comment: пробовал, тоже самое

Comment: Посмотрите в логах, нет ли ошибок, проверьте есть ли вообще сниппет getImageList

Comment: Если вызываете в шаблоне  поробуйте &docid=` `[[+id]]` `

Comment: получилось так: ***[[getImageList?
    &tvname=`material`
    &tpl=`@CODE: <li><a href="[[+pdf]]" target="_blank" download>[[+title]]</a></li>`
    ]]***

Comment: Плюс в настройках этого TV пришлось поменять "параметры вЫвода" с url на "по умолчанию"

Comment: ***Tunker***, спасибо в 'n'-ый раз!!!